# como envio a un cierto grupo de sockets?

Tags: nodejs, websocket

Estoy aprendiendo websockets, pero es dificil conseguir informacion relacionada a mis preguntas en la web. Uso express-ws y quiero enviar la informacion solo a los usuarios que sean parte de un grupo, Este grupo estará basado en el rol del usuario. El problema es que solo se mandar la informacion a todos o a un solo. Dejo parte del codigo

```
app.ws('/mensajes', (ws, req)=>{
  ws.on('message', msg => {
    const clients = expressWS.getWss().clients;
    clients.forEach(client => {
      client.send(msg);
    });
  });
});
```

Eso lo obtuve como respuesta a enviar a todos y funciona pero solo quiero enviar a un grupo especifico

Comment: Para poder mandarle a un "grupo" necesitas que cada cliente al registrarse envíe información sobre el "usuario". Con esa información después solo necesitas filtrar los clientes

Comment: ¿Cuál sería ese *grupo*? ¿Tienes una forma de determinarlos? ¿Serán sólo aquellos que han accedido a la ruta? Necesitamos más detalles. Con gusto te ayudamos. Saludos